# Azure Cross Cloud Auth using AAD

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-authentication, azure-identity, azure-gov, azure-entra-id

I'm trying to move non sensitive data from Azure Government Cloud to Public cloud. I read through links and understood AAD auth works for cross tenant access. I couldn't find anything on the cross cloud access. Is it possible for an application running in Government cloud to access public cloud resource using AAD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the appropriate configuration of Microsoft cloud settings, B2B collaboration, and cross-tenant access policies, an application in the Azure Government Cloud can access resources in the public cloud using Azure Active Directory for authentication and collaboration purposes.

[More Details on B2B collaboration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/external-id/b2b-government-national-clouds)